# STS not connecting to Marketplace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have both Eclipse version 4.6.3 & 4.13.0 installed. As well as STS 4.8.1.RELEASE.  The 2 Eclipse versions can connect to Eclipse Marketplace with no issues.  But I get the below error when connecting from STS.  I have compared network setting including my proxy.  It all looks the same.

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.17: Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.17.
Unable to read repository at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&os=win32&platform.version=4.17.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: *PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target* sounds like a problem with the certificate

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I added my keystore to the jre cacerts based on this article, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ.  I recycled STS and it gave the same error.  My SpringToolSuite4.ini has the following vm specified, -vm
plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.0.v20201014-1246/jre/.  This is where I updated the cacert.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall at a perhaps large security-conscious company?  Your firewall may do the same thing ours does, which is require an additional certificate created by that company. Your CSO should have some information about this.

Comment: My questions is why is this not occurring with any version of Eclipse that I have.  I seems to me that however Eclipse is configured could be be used to configure STS.